What can I put over this painted mortar/concrete?
The house I bought has some kind of concrete roughly smeared and painted on the front side of the house. I am looking for a fairly cheap solution to improve the look until I can afford to replace the siding. Any suggestions? Is there a product that will adhere to painted concrete?

No picture so guessing a badly done parching(thin mortar to smooth out blocks/rough concrete) job.

we do not know what you consider improved look

Likely Stucco or Parging. Perhaps even pebble-dash rendering if someone of a UK bent had at it. Given no picture, hard to say if it's a perfectly fine job that you don't like the look of or something actually done wrong.
